# Je vais coucher ou je vais me coucher?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes-pronominaux

Est-ce que la phrase :

> Je vais coucher.

est correcte ou doit on écrire

> Je vais **me** coucher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La première option signifie que tu vas coucher quelqu'un (comme mettre au lit un enfant) alors que la deuxième signifie que tu te couches. Cette version est probablement celle que tu voulais.

Comment: Cela signifie, que je ne peux pa dire seulement "je vais coucher", mais je dois dire "je vais coucher + ... (quelqu'un)?

Comment: Oui. tu ne peux pas dire "je veux coucher" seulement

Comment: Exact. Cela n'aurait pas de sens.

Comment: Pire, « je vais coucher. » (avec un point final) a plutôt des connotations sexuelles.

Answer (score 1):

Oui, « je veux coucher » est connoté sexuellement. Comparez « je vais me coucher. »
« Je vais coucher » has a sexual connotation. Please use « je vais **me** coucher» for *I'm going to bed* as in *to sleep.*

Comment: You use *je veux* in the French part of your reply but *je vais* in the English one..