# Coucher vs se coucher in "Voulez-vous coucher avec moi (ce soir)" ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

This phrase confuses me. My understanding is that the verb is *se coucher*, and so it ought to be *Voulez-vous vous coucher avec moi?*

I read [this related question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11486/je-vais-coucher-ou-je-vais-me-coucher) and it says I am correct, and that non-reflexive *coucher* means to put something to bed. So why does this phrase not used the reflexive version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(Se) coucher* has several meanings

**Se coucher** = to lie down, to go to bed

> *Je me couche tôt en semaine.*
>
> *Tu viens te coucher ?*

**Coucher quelqu'un** = to put someone in bed

> J'ai couché les enfants.

**Coucher avec quelqu'un** = to have sex with someone

> Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir ?
>
> Dans le cinéma, il faut coucher pour réussir.

And some other meanings.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @SteffX above is perfect, but I will take the liberty of adding a piece of advice: Never ever say that sentence ("Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir ?") to anybody. This statement is so blunt and in fine so rude that, except if you want to never see your interlocutor again, you should absolutely avoid to pronounce these words.

There are many other ways to let know, even quite explicitly, your desire for somebody. A very French way would be to write a short poetry in alexandrins.

Answer (score -1):

"Elle a couché avec son patron." : "She had sex with her boss.". "Couché" or "coucher" also mean "to have sex" when the complement is introduced by "avec" and names a person. If it only implies one person, then it means "to sleep" or "to lay down". If someone asks you "Would you like to sleep with me tonight?", there is a good chance he or she does not really want to sleep!

Comment: Cela ne répond pas à la question. Il est demandé la différence entre « coucher » et « se coucher. »

Answer (score -1):

Evpok  , si le verbe était « coucher avec », on dirait plutôt « Voulez vous couchez avec moi ? » et non « Voulez-vous vous coucher avec moi ? »  à moins que ça ne soit le verbe « se coucher » ;  regardez encore ou montrez cette phrase à quelqu'un de votre entourage qui puisse en juger.